# What does ContainingType mean in java method reference

Tags: java-8

In Java Method References

ContainingClass::staticMethodName - means that a class can refer the static method (Reference to a Static Method )

containingObject::instanceMethodName - means that a class object is created first and then that object is used to refer the instanceMethod .

My doubt is

ContainingType::methodName - what does the ContainingType mean ?

Is ContainingType a predefined class in java like String or something else ?

Comment: These are illegal in `Java`, before `Java8`... So you should change the tag.

Comment: Can you give a link of where you got this from?

Comment: @Sweeper https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

Answer (score 4):

Java Language Specification, [§4.3. Reference Types and Values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3):

> There are four kinds of *reference types*: class types ([§8.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1)), interface types ([§9.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.1)), type variables ([§4.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4)), and array types ([§10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.1)).

Array type don't have static methods, so that doesn't apply to static method reference, but you can do the other 3:

```
class MyClass {
    static void doIt() {/*doing it*/}
}
interface MyInterface {
    static void doIt() {/*doing it*/}
}
class Test<T extends MyClass> {
    void test() {
        Runnable m1 = MyClass::doIt;     // class type
        Runnable m2 = MyInterface::doIt; // interface type
        Runnable m3 = T::doIt;           // type variable
    }
}
```

---

Now that [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) is provided in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953818/what-does-containingtype-mean-in-java-method-reference/45954063#comment78865741_45953818), it says:

1. Reference to a static method
   `ContainingClass::staticMethodName`
2. Reference to an instance method of a particular object
   `containingObject::instanceMethodName`
3. Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type
   **`ContainingType::methodName`**
4. Reference to a constructor
   `ClassName::new`

Here, again, `ContainingType` refers to any of the 3 *reference types* mentioned above: Class, Interface, and Type Variable.

You can then make a method reference for any *instance method* of such a type.

```
class MyClass {
    void doIt() {/*doing it*/}
}
interface MyInterface {
    void doIt();
}
class Test<T extends MyClass> {
    void test() {
        Consumer<MyClass>     m1 = MyClass::doIt;
        Consumer<MyInterface> m2 = MyInterface::doIt;
        Consumer<T>           m3 = T::doIt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is not a working example . I made a few changes .                
 class MyClass {
    void doIt(String str) {System.out.println(str.toUpperCase());};
}        and inside test method I included this two lines    
         Consumer<String>     m1 = MyClass::doIt; m1.accept("Raj");

Comment: Runnable m1 = MyClass::doIt; this declaration comes in this case  
   (already covered ) 
  ContainingClass::staticMethodName .                                                                          I dont know why ContainingType::methodName is introduced ?

Comment: In this line Consumer<MyClass> m1 = MyClass::doIt; Myclass Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method doIt(String) . So Myclass is not a containing type

Comment: Here Myclass ( user defined ) cannot call a non-static method . But its not the same with built in String class in java  . String class can call its non static as well as static method  when used as method reference .

Comment: @RajGopalBhallamudi The first half of the answer was written before you posted the link to where "containing type" was used, so that part of the answer is generic, which is why it showed example with static method call. The second half of answer is a more direct answer to the use of "containing type" in the link you provided, and example was updated with instance method call of arbitrary object. --- And you're right, the example are not "working" examples, but simply shows the syntax for the various ways to create a method reference. They don't "work", but they do compile.

Comment: I think When it comes to user defined class then all the possibilities for method references are cover by this cases  . ContainingClass::staticMethodName ,containingObject::instanceMethodName , ClassName::new . and when it comes to predefined classes in java like String etc  then ContainingType::methodName comes in picture where ContainingType are the inbuilt classes in java and methodName are either static or non static methods . That was the reason why  String::compareToIgnoreCase was used as an example in documentation of Java by Oracle .

Comment: Consider this example https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html                                   Here Arrays.sort(rosterAsArray,Person::compareByAge); works fine because compareByAge is a static method  but if static modifier is removed from compareAge then we rewrite the statement as Arrays.sort(rosterAsArray,new Person()::compareByAge) . This was the reason another example was included Arrays.sort(stringArray, String::compareToIgnoreCase); that used String inbuilt class .

Comment: In our example we write String::compareToIgnoreCase which is not possible according to rule 1 of method references ContainingClass::staticMethodName . but the statement is perfectly valid and gets executed . So ContainingType has to be is a predefined class but not user defined class .

Comment: @RajGopalBhallamudi 1) There is **no difference** whatsoever between a predefined class and a user-defined class. --- 2) Seems you didn't read, or didn't understand, the difference between `ContainingClass::staticMethodName` and `ContainingType::methodName`. The second refers to an *instance* (i.e. non-static) method. The example defines a method reference for the functional interface `Comparator<String>` with method `compare(T o1, T o2)`. The `String.compareToIgnoreCase(String str)` can implement that method, with `o1` becoming `this`, and `o2` becoming `str`.

Comment: I too know there is no difference whatsoever between a predefined class and a user-defined class . But  Arrays.sort(stringArray, String::compareToIgnoreCase) is illegal . since String is a class and compareToIgnoreCase is a non static method . This line String::compareToIgnoreCase means that String class is referring a static method named compareToIgnoreCase which should raise an error . I hope you understand my point . Java is not treating the user defined and built in classes in same way . For more clarity just  include compareToIgnoreCase inside Person class and see what happens.

Comment: @RajGopalBhallamudi Try reading what I've written. `String::compareToIgnoreCase` is ***NOT*** referring to a static method. `String` is a *class*, hence also a *type*, so it is the *containing type* of the *instance* method `compareToIgnoreCase`. The second part of my answer shows example of this for user-defined class (`Consumer<MyClass> m1 = MyClass::doIt`), proving that it can be done for all classes, not just built-in classes.

Comment: @RajGopalBhallamudi I don't know what you mean by "just include compareToIgnoreCase inside Person class and see what happens". If you have problem with something like that, *create a new question*, show the relevant code, and we might be able to help you understand what you're doing wrong.

Comment: This is a small example . A user defined  class cannot refer to an instance  method in this way  - ContainingClass::staticMethodName   . -----------------            
interface Myinter
{
 void doit(String s);
}
public class Myclass implements Myinter {

 @Override
 public void doit(String s) {
  System.out.println("hi");
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {  
     Consumer<String> m2 =Myclass::doit;     
 }
}----------------

Comment: @RajGopalBhallamudi Which part of "**create a new question**" didn't you understand? Since you apparently ignore almost everything I say, I'm done talking to you. Good luck finding others to help you.

Comment: I am also done talking to you . You tried to convince me syntactically but I want a working example .

Comment: Arrays.sort(stringArray, String::compareToIgnoreCase) is illegal (A class cannot refer to a instance method)  . I will show another possible way to do the  same . ----- class ComparisonProvider
  { 
   public int CompareFunction(String a,String b)
   {
    return a.compareToIgnoreCase(b);
   }

  }
  ComparisonProvider myComparisonProvider=new ComparisonProvider();
  String[]stringArray={"Barbara","James","Mary","John","Patricia","Robert","Michael","Linda"};
  Arrays.sort( stringArray,myComparisonProvider::CompareFunction);
  for(String s:stringArray)
   System.out.println(s+" ");

Comment: `Arrays.sort(stringArray, String::compareToIgnoreCase);` is **not** illegal. See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/GDRV0Z) for proof.

Comment: you are genius . Great proof . A class as well as an object can also refer the instance method . Thank you for the example

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for being so patient and helping with your knowledge. ▲

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

In the document you gave,there is a example of the ContainingType:

```
String[] stringArray = { "Barbara", "James", "Mary", "John",
          "Patricia", "Robert", "Michael", "Linda" };
Arrays.sort(stringArray, String::compareToIgnoreCase);
```

and explains:

> The equivalent lambda expression for the method reference String::compareToIgnoreCase would have the formal parameter list (String a, String b), where **a and b are arbitrary names** used to better describe this example. The method reference would invoke the method a.compareToIgnoreCase(b).

I think,the element of the stringArray dosen't have a name (eg: String s1 = "Barbara"),so you can't refer it by containingObject::instanceMethodName(eg:s1::compareToIgnoreCase). That's why it uses ContainingType.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `ContainingType::methodName` is a general/common form of the 2 forms above...

Answer (score 0):

Think about the below code. You can replace the `<methodReference>` width

- `InterfaceA::method`     (for ContainingType::methodName)
- `ClassA::method`         (for also ContainingType::methodName)
- `ClassB::instanceMethod` (for ContainingObject::instanceMethodName) or
- `ClassB::staticMethod`   (for ContainingClass::staticMethodName)

to demonstrate the mentioned cases:

```
public class App {
    interface InterfaceA {
        String method();
    }
    static class ClassA implements InterfaceA {
        public String method() {
            return "ContainingType::methodName";
        }
    }
    static class ClassB extends ClassA {
        public String instanceMethod() {
            return "ContainingObject::instanceMethodName";
        }
        public static String staticMethod(ClassB classB) {
            return "ContainingClass::staticMethodName";
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(((Function<ClassB, String>) <methodReference>).apply(new ClassB()));
    }
}
```